# Couldnt upload My flask application on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, heroku-postgres

I have a flask application with postgresql db So the steps are:

```
1.gunicorn
2.Procfile
3.heroku login
4.heroku apps:create flask-lili
5.heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
6.heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE_URL
7.sudo pip install psycopg2
8.pip freeze> requirements.txt
10.git add .
11.git commit -m "create requirements.txt"
12.git push origin master
13.git push heroku master
14.heroku open
```

I got no error when I run command git push heroku master, But Not sure that should I use command number 5 and 6 or Not

the Procfile :

```
web: gunicorn manage:app
init: python manage.py db init
upgrade: python manage.py db upgrade
migrate: python manage.py db migrate
```

config.py:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = 'Thisismysecretkey'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL',
             'postgresql+psycopg2://peg:1234@localhost/app')
    print SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI


class TestingConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL',
        'postgresql+psycopg2://peg:1234@localhost/testapp')
    print SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False


config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
    'default': DevelopmentConfig}
```

The error:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Thanx if You could help me
Now I run command heroku logs --tail:

```
2015-03-09T12:17:29.670249+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by peg@gmail.com
2015-03-09T12:17:29.670286+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by peg1@gmail.com
2015-03-09T12:21:36.990904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn manage:app`
    2015-03-09T12:21:38.880134+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

even though I have gunicorn in my requirements

if I run "heroku run init" will get error:

```
File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.migrate
```

I can run the application locally with no errors and I have flask-migrate in requirements.txt

Comment: can you please add a logger so you can use `heroku --logs`? You can just log application logs to `sys.stderr` and Heroku will catch them for you

Comment: it would not necessarily help you upload the application, but it will allow you to see the traceback as to exactly what is going wrong. You can use [this documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/) to add a logger. For heroku, use [this logging hander to sys.stderr](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler)

Comment: What is the gunicorn step mean? What's in your requirements.txt?

Comment: gunicorn==19.3.0 is in my requirements.txt @dirn

Comment: try using `gunicorn==17.5`. 19.3 exits with some errors

Comment: When people use `sudo` to install and dump `pip freeze` into a requirements file, they often get a lot of stuff they don't want. Some of that can cause problems. What's in your requirements.txt?

Comment: I'd suggest cleaning up your requirements.txt. There's a lot of stuff in there and I'm sure your app doesn't use it all (e.g., adium-theme-ubuntu). I don't know that this is the problem, but Heroku could be failing if there's something it can't install.

Comment: Thanx @dirn I make new virtualenv with only neccessary requirements.txt But still couldnt do heroku open https://github.com/peggykh/JunagleMonks2 Can you help please got error [1:1:0310/133136:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

Answer (score 2):

flask.ext is deprecated

change flask.ext.migrate to flask_migrate hence code lines go as

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```

instead of

```
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```

refer this documentation

Flask-Migrate 
https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from

```
flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```

To

```
flask_Migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
```